# 2 javascripts not working with each other

Tags: javascript, conflict

I have 2 javascripts who aren't working together. They both work separately, but when put together only one works. This is how I called them

```
    window.onload = initImages;
    window.onload = countdown(year,month,day,hour,minute);
```

If I put "window.onload = initImages;" after "countdown", then only images work, if it stays like this when countdown is after images, then only countdown works.

```
// JavaScript Document


function initImages() {
    for (var x = 0; x < document.images.length; x++)
    {
        document.images[x].onclick = povecana;
    }
}
function povecana() {

    dir = "images/" + this.id + ".jpg";

    if (undefined != window.proz)
    {
        proz.style.opacity = 0.6;
    }
    proz = document.getElementById(this.id);
    proz.style.opacity = 1;

    slika = document.getElementById("odabranaSlika");   

    slika.style.display= "block";
    slika.innerHTML='<img src='+ dir +' " width="100%" height="450px" />';

    jabuke = document.getElementById("default");
    jabuke.style.display= "none";   

    tekst = document.getElementById("tekstOdabrane");
    tekst.style.display = "block";

    if (this.id=="slika1")
    tekst.innerHTML="Idared je američka sorta nastala 1935.";
    else (this.id=="slika2")
    tekst.innerHTML="Fuji je zasigurno jedna od atraktivnijih";
}

/*
Count down until any date script-
By JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
Over 200+ free scripts here!
Modified by Robert M. Kuhnhenn, D.O. 
on 5/30/2006 to count down to a specific date AND time,
on 10/20/2007 to a new format, and 1/10/2010 to include
time zone offset.
*/

/*  Change the items noted in light blue below to create your countdown target date and announcement once the target date and time are reached.  */
var current="Winter is here!";//-->enter what you want the script to display when the target date and time are reached, limit to 20 characters
var year=2013;      //-->Enter the count down target date YEAR
var month=12;        //-->Enter the count down target date MONTH
var day=21;         //-->Enter the count down target date DAY
var hour=18;        //-->Enter the count down target date HOUR (24 hour clock)
var minute=38;      //-->Enter the count down target date MINUTE
var tz=+1;          //-->Offset for your timezone in hours from UTC (see http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/index.htm to find the timezone offset for your location)

//-->    DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW!    <--
var montharray=new Array("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");

function countdown(yr,m,d,hr,min){
    theyear=yr;themonth=m;theday=d;thehour=hr;theminute=min;
    var today=new Date();
    var todayy=today.getYear();
    if (todayy < 1000) {todayy+=1900;}
    var todaym=today.getMonth();
    var todayd=today.getDate();
    var todayh=today.getHours();
    var todaymin=today.getMinutes();
    var todaysec=today.getSeconds();
    var todaystring1=montharray[todaym]+" "+todayd+", "+todayy+" "+todayh+":"+todaymin+":"+todaysec;
    var todaystring=Date.parse(todaystring1)+(tz*1000*60*60);
    var futurestring1=(montharray[m-1]+" "+d+", "+yr+" "+hr+":"+min);
    var futurestring=Date.parse(futurestring1)-(today.getTimezoneOffset()*(1000*60));
    var dd=futurestring-todaystring;
    var dday=Math.floor(dd/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
    var dhour=Math.floor((dd%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1);
    var dmin=Math.floor(((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1);
    var dsec=Math.floor((((dd%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1);
    if(dday<=0&&dhour<=0&&dmin<=0&&dsec<=0){
        document.getElementById('count2').innerHTML=current;
        document.getElementById('count2').style.display="inline";
        document.getElementById('count2').style.width="390px";
        document.getElementById('dday').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('dhour').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('dmin').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('dsec').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('days').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('hours').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('minutes').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('seconds').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('spacer1').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('spacer2').style.display="none";
        return;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('count2').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('dday').innerHTML=dday;
        document.getElementById('dhour').innerHTML=dhour;
        document.getElementById('dmin').innerHTML=dmin;
        document.getElementById('dsec').innerHTML=dsec;
        setTimeout("countdown(theyear,themonth,theday,thehour,theminute)",1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you call the second function from the 1st function??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
    initImages();
    countdown(year,month,day,hour,minute);
}
```

They are being overwritten. You can't assign two values to one variable!

For example,

```
x = 5;
x = 10;
```

Of course, `x` will be `10`. Well, it is the same for you: `window.onload` is like `x` and the numbers are like your functions.

Comment: Thank you very much! that was fast answer :D

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = func1;
window.onload = func2;
```

in this case always func 2 will be called as you have changed the onload handler from func1 to func2 after the 2nd statement;

try

```
window.onload = function(){
  func1();
  func2();
}
```